# Hide title in header of my Dokuwiki

Tags: title, dokuwiki

Because I'm using a logo in my header, I don't need the title-text. But I would like to have a browser-title. 
So I need to set a title and have to hide it in the header - but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your wiki looks like dokuwiki.org (meaning that you are using one of recent versions and default template). If not the approach still should be the same, search for `$conf['title']` in your template.

There is a block in lib/tpl/dokuwiki/tpl_header.php:

```
        // display logo and wiki title in a link to the home page
        tpl_link(
            wl(),
            '<img src="'.$logo.'" '.$logoSize[3].' alt="" /> <span>'.$conf['title'].'</span>',
            'accesskey="h" title="[H]"'
        );
```

Remove `<span>'.$conf['title'].'</span>` from it.

Each update of Dokuwiki engine will overwrite this change. You'll need to repeat it manually after each update or copy paste doku template into a new one and update this new template manually.

Answer (score 4):

Possible also to hide the title text with a proper CSS `display: none` setting. It can be put into the `conf/userstyle.css` file, so it wont be overwritten by updates. The text resides still in the page but becomes invisible. It may improve the search-engine hits also, maybe.

Possible CSS code:

```
div.headings h1 span { display: none !important; }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Possible also to hide the title text with a proper CSS display: none setting. It can be put into the conf/userstyle.css file, so it wont be overwritten by updates. The text resides still in the page but becomes invisible. It may improve the search-engine hits also, maybe.
>
> Possible CSS code:
>
> `div.headings h1 span { display: none !important; }`

This is the good answer. It works for me.